# Sum two arrays element-by-element in Java

Tags: java, arrays

What is the easiest way to sum two arrays element-by-element?

I know that you can use a `for` loop such as the following:

```
int[] a = {0, 1, 2};
int[] b = {3, 4, 5};
int[] c = new int[a.length];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

But in languages such as MATLAB, you can do the element-by-element array sum by just writing `c = a + b`. Is there an easy way to do this in Java?

The method that comes to mind is using the RealVector class from Apache Commons Math, but that method is rather verbose.

Comment: Can't get any simpler than what you have.

Comment: You cant do it with standard arrays in Java, but look up some matricies classes. Im sure they have summation methodes you are looking for that are also highly optimized.

Comment: @Dgrin91 More optimized than what he wrote above?

Comment: @crush Yes, via threading.

Comment: @Dgrin91 Why in the world would you multi-thread this...I guess if it was a huge array, you could split it into chunks...

Comment: @crush Yes... the threading assumes it is not a trivial example. Always assume a massive input. If it is a trivial example though the threading would likely slow it down a tiny bit, but not by a noticeable amount.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's certainly nothing to enable this in the *language*. I don't know of anything in the standard libraries either, but it's trivial to put the code you've written into a utility method which you can call from anywhere you need it.

Comment: It is just me who thinks it's crazy that the standard libraries don't have things like elementwise addition?  It seems like a pretty basic missing feature for a language with as many bells and whistles as Java.

Comment: @Peter google for operator overloading. Whole lot of people don't want it... So its not in Java while c++ has it.

Answer (score 5):

One more answer, using streams and providing a more generic solution:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SOTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        int[] a = {0, 1, 2};
        int[] b = {3, 4, 5};

        int[] sum = applyOn2Arrays((x, y) -> x + y, a, b);
        int[] diff = applyOn2Arrays((x, y) -> x - y, a, b);
        int[] mult = applyOn2Arrays((x, y) -> x * y, a, b);


        Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int [] {3,5,7}, sum);
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int [] {-3,-3,-3}, diff);
        Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int [] {0,4,10}, mult);
    }

    private int[] applyOn2Arrays(IntBinaryOperator operator, int[] a, int b[]) {
        return IntStream.range(0, a.length)
                .map(index -> operator.applyAsInt(a[index], b[index]))
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check this one: used sum and carry

```
public class SumOfTwoArrays{    

    public static int[] sumOfTwoArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){

        int na = arr1.length;
        int nb = arr2.length;
        int nc;
        int min;

        if(na > nb){
            nc = na + 1;
            min = nb;
        }else{
            nc = nb + 1;
            min = na;
        }

        int[] c = new int[nc];
        int sum = 0;
        int carry = 0;
        int i = na - 1;
        int j = nb - 1;
        int k = nc - 1;

        while(i >= 0 && j>=0){
            sum  = arr1[i] + arr2[j] + carry;
            i--;
            j--;
            c[k] = sum % 10;
            sum = sum / 10;
            carry = sum % 10;
            k--;        
        }//end of while loop

        while(i >= 0){          //n2 has exhausted
            sum  = arr1[i] + carry;
            c[k] = sum % 10;
            sum = sum / 10;
            carry = sum % 10;
            i--;
            k--;
        }

        while(j >= 0){        //n1 has exhausted  
            sum  = arr2[j] + carry;
            c[k] = sum % 10;
            sum = sum / 10;
            carry = sum % 10;
            k--;        
            j--;
        }

        c[k] = carry;

        return c;
    }
}
```

Input: 
arr1 = {2, 1, 3};
arr2 = {3, 2};

Output:
c: {0, 2, 4 ,5}

Answer (score 1):

> `c = a + b` Is there an easy way to do this in Java?

No. not this easy, because you can not override operators in java.

You could use [javax.vecmath.Vector3d](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/Vector3d.html) (as @crush said it in another comment [credits to him]) which supports [add](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/Tuple3d.html#add%28javax.vecmath.Tuple3d%29) but this does nothing more than adding the values:

```
/**
  * Sets the value of this tuple to the vector sum of itself and tuple t1.
  * @param t1  the other tuple
  */
public final void add(Tuple3d t1) {
    x += t1.x;
    y += t1.y;
    z += t1.z;
}
```

you use it like this:

```
vectorC = vectorA.copy().add(vectorB);
//you need to copy the vectorA because add manipulates the object your calling it on
```

or Use library such as [JScience](http://jscience.org/) which has a mathematical-[Vektor](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/Vector.html)

**But if you want a performant way: your solution is the best you can get in my opinion!**

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 Streams it's very easy to do this. And this method is very efficient when adding a large array size.

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       Integer arrSize = scan.nextInt();
       Integer firstArr[] = new Integer[arrSize];
       Integer secArr[] = new Integer[arrSize];
       Integer sumArr[] = new Integer[arrSize];
       for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) firstArr[i] = scan.nextInt();
       for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) secArr[i] = scan.nextInt();
       IntStream.range(0, arrSize).forEach(i -> sumArr[i] = firstArr[i] + secArr[i]);
       System.out.println(Arrays.asList(sumArr).stream().map(n->n.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition of array value with their number like `21+9 = 30`. when `9+1=10` tens place value get borrowed and added to tens place.
Where form java 8 the result is `21+9 = 210`.

```
Array 1      +  Array 2    = Reslut Array    ~ Java8 Result

{0, 1, 2}    +  {3, 4, 9}  = [0, 3, 6, 1]    ~ [3, 5, 11]
{0, 1, 2, 1} +  {3, 4, 9}  = [0, 0, 4, 7, 0] ~ [3, 5, 11, 1]
```

---

Simple java logic to all two arrays values into single array:

> NOTE: First array's length must be greater than Second array's length.

```java
public static int[] arraysAddition_Int(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    int borrowing = 0;
    int[] resultArr = new int[a1.length+1];
    for (int i = a1.length - 1, j = a2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--, j--) {
        int n1 = a1[i];
        int n2 = 0;
        if (j >= 0) {
            n2 = a2[j];
        }

        int temp = n1 + n2 + borrowing;
        borrowing = 0; // After adding make it as ZERO.

        if (temp > 9) {
            borrowing = 1;
            temp -= 10;
        }
        resultArr[i+1] = temp;
    }
    if (borrowing > 0) {
        resultArr[0] = borrowing;
    }
    System.out.format("[%s + %s]=[%s]\n --- \n",
           Arrays.toString(a1), Arrays.toString(a2), Arrays.toString(resultArr));
    return resultArr;
}
```

Using Java 8:

```java
private static int[] arraysAddition_java8(int[] a, int b[]) {
    int startInclusive = 0, endExclusive = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    IntUnaryOperator mapper = index -> (index < a.length ? a[index] : 0) + (index < b.length ? b[index] : 0);

    return IntStream.range(startInclusive, endExclusive).map(mapper).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = {12, 13, 14, 44};
    int b[] = {11, 10, 15, 20, 50};
    int[] cs = new int[a.length];
    System.out.println("----------------------FIRST TABLE--------------------------------");
    for (int i : a) {
        System.out.println("Element : " + i);
    }

    System.out.println("----------------------SECOND TABLE -----------------------------");

    for (int j : b) {
        System.out.println("Element : " + j);
    }


    System.out.println("-----------------------SUM OF TABLE------------------------------------");

    if (a.length == b.length) {
        for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < a.length; i++, j++, k++) {
            cs[k] = a[i] + b[j];
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Arrays have different length");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] a = {0, 1, 2};
        int[] b = {3, 4, 5};
        int[] c = new int[a.length];
        if(a.length==b.length) {
        for (int i = 0 ,j=0,k=0; i < a.length; i++,j++,k++) {
            c[k] = a[i] + b[j];

            System.out.println(c[k]);
        }}
        else {
            System.out.println("Should be same length in two arrays");

        }

    }

}
```